# Equation relating extremal properties of graphs to probability of a cycle existing

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, random-graphs, hamiltonian-path, eulerian-path

Does some function exist that takes a desired probability of a certain cycle existing in a random graph as input and outputs the extremal properties of a graph to achieve that probability?

For example, is there a way to answer a question of the form 'what is the smallest number of nodes/edges such that the probability that a random graph contains an Eulerian/Hamiltonian cycle is less than *p*'?

Answer (score 1):

For the usual types of random graphs, the probability of existence of a Hamiltonian cycle will be essentially impossible to compute, however the expected number of Hamiltonian cycles is very easy: you just take the probability of a particular possibility being a cycle
and multiply by the number of possible cycles.  If the expected number of Hamiltonian cycles is less than $1$, that gives you an upper bound on the probability of there being a Hamiltonian cycle.